# How get PostgreSQL version using psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have the follow statements:

```
from alembic import op
conn = op.get_bind()
```

Now I want to get postgresql version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to documentation it is [server_version](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.server_version) property of connection:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(settings.DB_DSN)
>>> conn.server_version
90504
```

> The number is formed by converting the major, minor, and revision numbers into two-decimal-digit numbers and appending them together. For example, version 8.1.5 will be returned as 80105.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run raw SQL queries, just run the following:

```
SELECT version();
```

Comment: There is also `show server_version;` or `select current_setting('server_version');` to get just a version number without details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu then you can execute command

```
psql -V
```

to check postgresql version where

```
V must be in capital.
```

and to check version of psycopg2 you can run following command

```
pip freeze | grep psycopg2
```

alternatively you can execute

```
pip freeze
```

to show all the installed packages with their respective version

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import psycopg2

conn_str = {
        'user': os.environ['USERNAME'].lower(),
        'host': 'POSTGES_SERVER_NAME',
        'port': 5432,
        'database': 'database_name'
    }

conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_str)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT VERSION()')
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
cursor.close()

# output:
# ('PostgreSQL 10.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit',)
```